# ConvertTableToCsvFile_roads Attribute Error 'module' object has no attribute

Tags: arcpy, csv

I am trying to convert shp to csv.  I found the documentation here for ArcMap 10.3:
http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/roads-and-highways-toolbox/convert-table-to-csv-file.htm
but I keep getting

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ConvertTableToCsvFile_roads'
```

I am using ArcMap 10.5.  Is this module no longer supported?  What would be the alternative for ArcMap 10.5?

```
def write_csv(poly_count, map_location):
    in_table = poly_count
    out_table = map_location + "poly_count.csv"
    print('in_table: {}'.format(in_table))
    print('out_table: {}'.format(out_table))
    #Converts the polycount shapefile to a csv that get_count() will use
    print('Converting poly_count shapefile to csv')
    csv_file = arcpy.ConvertTableToCsvFile_roads(in_table, out_csv_file, 'COMMA')
    print('CSV Conversion worked like a charm')
    return csv_file
```

Comment: Do you have the Roads and Highways extension? If not use TableToTable http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001200000027000000 or Copy Rows http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//0017000000n4000000 or Table Select http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//000800000007000000 all three do fairly much the same thing with only a few subtle differences.

Comment: Ahh thank you, I was hoping I'd be able to use the module for normal shapefiles.  The TableToTable_conversion worked out.  I original did not use it because .shp is not listed in the table formats, so I wasn't sure if it would work.  http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/conversion/table-to-table.htm

Comment: Yes, that's a bit of a trap. As it turns out *any* spatial data is a table and can be treated as such. It makes a bit more sense from the ArcObjects side of things but I'll see if I can simplify it: A feature class *has or is* a table but a table is not necessarily a feature class. This relationship is worth remembering, or being aware of at least, because it has ramifications as you get more experienced with arcpy.

Comment: Good to know, I'll remember that as I work more with automating processes involving shapefiles.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you will see from its [Licensing Information](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/roads-and-highways-toolbox/convert-table-to-csv-file.htm#L_):

```
ArcGIS for Desktop Basic: Requires Roads and Highways
ArcGIS for Desktop Standard: Requires Roads and Highways
ArcGIS for Desktop Advanced: Requires Roads and Highways
```

the [Convert Table To CSV File](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/roads-and-highways-toolbox/convert-table-to-csv-file.htm) tool needs [Esri Roads and Highways](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/guide-books/extensions/roads-and-highways/what-is-roads-and-highways.htm) installed and licensed.

The AttributeError that you are receiving indicates that you do not have it installed and licensed.